# How to get PKGBUILD of a given package?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pacman

My goal is to create list of configuration files that are tracked by pacman (those that are normally saved even after removal of the package with the .pacsave suffix). I haven't found a way to get such information from pacman directly, so now I want to do this by extracting the `backup` section from PKGBUILD of those packages. I would assume that there would be straightforward way of doing this, because it needs to be done as a step in installing any package, but I can't find much information about it. How would I go about getting (possibly downloading) PKGBUILD file of package installed via pacman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pacman -Qii <name>` or even `expac %B <name>` to get a list of its "backup" files.

You can use `asp update && asp show <name>` to automatically download the correct PKGBUILD. Every package's webpage at https://packages.archlinux.org also contains a link to its "Source Files" which includes the PKGBUILD.

Currently all packages for the official Arch repositories are kept in a SVN repository, which is usually accessed through a svn2git mirror at:

- https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git – for [core] and [extra]
- https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git – for [community]

The locations and structure of these repositories may change soon.